Do rules of statutory construction apply to administrative code? [TX]
I am wondering if the rules of statutory construction governing statues passed by the legislature also apply to administrative codes in Texas. Specifically, 16 TAC § 26.111(g), which states "... an applicant must have principals, consultants or permanent employees in managerial positions whose combined experience in the telecommunications industry equals or exceeds five years." In Texas, TEX. GOV’T CODE ANN. §§ 311.012(b), 312.003(b) state that the plural include the singular, and vice versa, but since that governs civil statues, and this is an administrative regulation, I'm not sure if I can cite the Texas Gov't code article. Any information on what rules of construction are applicable here would be appreciated.

There are multiple close votes requesting details or clarity but no comments indicating what is requested. I am voting to leave this open as it has received an answer, but encourage anyone casting close votes to provide comments to help the querent improve the question.

State regulations are interpreted under basically the same body of law as statutes.

In Texas, TEX. GOV’T CODE ANN. §§ 311.012(b), 312.003(b) state that
the plural include the singular, and vice versa, but since that
governs civil statues, and this is an administrative regulation, I'm
not sure if I can cite the Texas Gov't code article.

By its terms, it applies only to statutes, so you could use the citation signal "Cf." (which is short for either Latin confer or conferatur, both meaning "compare"), rather than the citation signal "See" (which means that the citation directly supports your point).
However, referencing statutory construction rules isn't very problematic when applied to state regulations, because with rare exceptions, the statutory rules of construction in Texas and pretty much all other states, simply codify the common law rules of construction that existed before those statutes were enacted.
Strictly speaking, but writing "Cf. TEX. GOV’T CODE ANN. §§ 311.012(b), 312.003(b)", you are arguing that the state regulation should be interpreted in the same way based upon the parallel common law rule of construction.
